# Processamento de Texto em arquivo csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv, padrão-de-texto

Estou com uma base de dados com mais de mil opiniões(texto) em um arquivo csv, no entanto eu preciso que apenas textos que contem mais de 5 palavras fiquem no meu arquivo. O problema é fazer um codigo que percorra todo o documento linha por linha e deixasse apenas opiniões que tem mais de 5 palavras, já pesquisei algumas bibliotecas e não tive exito nesta implementação.

Estou usando este código para leitura do arquivo:

```
import csv
lines = []
finalLines = []

 with open('aborto.csv') as csvfile:
   readerCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   print(readerCSV)

 for row in readerCSV:
    print(row)
```

Entrada: 
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
  Saida:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a organização do arquivo? Cada linha é uma opinião? E se houver vírgulas dentro do texto?

Comment: Exatamente este meu problema, como as virgulas são delimitadores estou confuso como prosseguir com código.

Comment: Ok, mas você criou um CSV, que utiliza a vírgula como delimitador, para guardar textos que possuem vírgula? Tem como [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um trecho do seu arquivo CSV?

Comment: Adicionei uma foto do terminal quando eu executo meu codigo

Comment: Acho que entendeu errado. Adicione um trecho do arquivo **CSV** que será lido pelo Python.

Comment: Veja se está correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente você precisa corrigir as indentações do seu código. Veja um exemplo já utilizando o processo de escrita do CSV:

```
import csv

# Abre o arquivo de saída para escrita:
with open("data.csv", 'r') as file_read, open('output.csv', 'w') as file_write:

    # Define o leitor CSV do arquivo:
    reader = csv.reader(file_read, delimiter=' ')

    # Define o escritor CSV do arquivo:
    writer = csv.writer(file_write, delimiter=' ')

    # Percorre as linhas do arquivo de entrada:
    for row in reader:

        # Verifica se o tamanho da linha é maior que o desejado:
        if len(row) > 5:

            # Escreve a linha no arquivo de saída:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Refiz o código com sua representação, mais quando chega em determinada linha (linha 117) para de reescrever no arquivo de saída.

Comment: @RivaldoHater altere o `delimiter` para um espaço em branco, tal como fiz após editar a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado.